# Is it better to scan a table, or to create just one hash key?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm developing iOS app, using Swift, and I need to be able to get the posts based on how close they are to a certain location, and sort them based on when they were posted.

I know how to check how close one item's post location is to another location, but, my problem is that I need to get all of the posts within a x miles of the user.

Would it be better to `scan` the table, which as I understand, selects every single value from the database, and then check if every item returned is within x miles of the user? This seems resource-intensive, as I'm expecting for there to be a lot of posts.

Or, would it be better to create another table that has a static hash key, and set two local secondary indexes, one for the latitude, and one for the longitude, and just query for that one static hash key, and query where the latitude is between x and y, and the longitude is between a and b?

The [AWS DynamoDB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html) warns against using a hash key that is accessed too much:

[image]

But is it really as bad as they make it seem to use the same hash key?

This would be in a table with the following values for a static hash key, where Post ID is the ID of the actual post.

```
**static hash key** | **latitude (local secondary index)** | **longitude (local secondary index)** | **dateCreated (local secondary index) | **Post ID**
```

and for the scan option:

```
**ID** | **latitude ** | **longitude ** | **date created ** | **poster** | **comments** | **flags** | **upvotes** | **downvotes** | **popularity**
```

Would having a static key be better than scanning a table performance-wise? How about cost-wise?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [dynamodb-geo from awslabs](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo)? It might help you model your geospatial data using DynamoDB.

Comment: Have you looked at objc's and swift (@dynamic)'s getValueForKeyPath and NSPredicate?

Comment: @AlexBrown Yes, That would be how I would sort the data if I used the `scan` method, instead of the `static hash key` method.

Comment: @MikeKobit I just did. One of the problems that I can see with it is that they stress how important it is to use it on the backend, and not directly in the app. I will defiantly look at how it parses geospatial data, and use that in my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow the guidelines**. We are suffering from two problems in production because of bad hashes. So my advice to you is to drop the static hash concept. It won't scale at a reasonable price, and will be a pain to monitor.

Building on top of the scan approach, you can reason about using Global Secondary Indices on the lat/lang attributes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. From what I understand of Global Secondary Indexes, it creates a separate hash and range key. Would it be better to use a Local Secondary Index, which only creates new range keys, and not new hash keys?

Comment: I'm not a GEO data expert so I can't foresee your query requirements. I was just pointing out the other index possible. Personally I don't like them both and I prefer to de-normalize the data and create table-per-query with data duplication.